# open air application by window hotkeys

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am developing flex air application.I have to implement hot-key functionality in air application.

For example whenever user press any two keys like ctr and S keys the open flex air application.
and whenever user press any two keys like ctr and q keys then close flex air application.

Is it possible in flex?

Thanks

Comment: stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown).         This code is only working when focus on the application.I have store application in system tray but when i use any hot-key it does not work.If there is any other way let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for a not-running program to intercept key commands. As such you cannot tell the application to start on some key command; either the program needs to run already, or you need to set that key command to the OS (you can do that in Windows in the properties panel for example).

The other command is rather easy, just listen for KeyDown events and check if your combination was pressed; and if so, quit the application.

Comment: To extend this answer for listening for key events, do `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);` which will return a `KeyboardEvent` which has a keyCode and a charCode as well as several flags for if ctrl/alt/shift is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.

For this kind of functionality you need a daemon or a background process. Because in AIR it's not possible to listen for keys when not focused (alias key logger) it would have to be a native application (different versions for different OS).

An alternative would be to somehow set a key stroke in the OS configuration - but then again, this is very different on different OS, and it is not supported by AIR - a native process would be required, too.

If you want to make this simple, it's not possible, unless you really want to invest a lot of time to write these processes, one for each different OS.

Comment: stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown); which will return a KeyboardEvent which has a keyCode and a charCode as well as several flags for if ctrl/alt/shift is This code works when focus on the application

Comment: i dont think catching keycode in air is possible. Firstly there is the security concerns. adobe does put up a lot of security based limitations. You will need to have a background application thats listening to keycodes, some daemon program. It does sound like a keylogger. Flex only gets keyboard events when it has got focus.